# Discord.py Creating a new channel and role of off a template

Tags: python, discord.py

So im trying to create a channel and a role based on what the user asked for in the command.

As an example:

```
User: >newrealm (realmname) (emoji)
```

So far I have this:

```py
@commands.command()
  async def newrealm(self, ctx,* , reason):
    reason = reason.split(' ')
    realm, emoji = reason
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    color = discord.Colour(0x3498DB)
    await guild.create_role(name= realm + " OP", color = color)
    await guild.create_text_channel(realm + emoji, category = 777360644252762123) #issue here
    await ctx.send("Created Channel and Role!")
```

But I am getting a traceback there.

```
Ignoring exception in command newrealm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SolarisTurtleMain/cogs/RealmCMD.py", line 55, in newrealm
    await guild.create_text_channel(realm + emoji, category = 777360644252762123)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 905, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 823, in _create_channel
    parent_id = category.id if category else None
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: The documentation for [create_text_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) says category should be a [CategoryChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#categorychannel). Where does `777360644252762123` come from?

Comment: That's the category's ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `category` argument is expecting a `CategoryChannel` object but you're passing it an `int`. You can use [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel) to get the `CategoryChannel`:

```py
category_channel = guild.get_channel(777360644252762123)
```

Then pass it to the `create_text_channel` function:

```py
await guild.create_text_channel(realm + emoji, category = category_channel)
```